# jQuery click event on paste not retaining textbox value

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox with the id "websiteaddress" and a button with the id "getwebsiteinfo". I'm wanting to fire the click event for the button when something is pasted into the textbox, it works, however the textbox loses what was posted in it. Here is my code. Any ideas on how I can get this working?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("input#websiteaddress").bind("paste", function() {
                            $("input#getwebsiteinfo").click();
                            return true;
                        });
                    }); 
                </script>
```

Comment: I do not have this same problem. Is there anything other jquery you are't showing us for these forms? Can you post the html?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. My textbox does not have the same issue as yours did, it retains the text. I did have an issue with the click event not being able to grab the pasted text, so i added a settimeout function to allow it time to get the new value.

**JSFIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/seadonk/vuh7qd4q/

```
   $().ready(function () {
    $("input#getwebsiteinfo").click(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){         
            var websiteaddress = $("input#websiteaddress").val();   
            alert('BUTTON CLICK: websiteaddress');
        });
    });

    $("input#websiteaddress").bind("paste", function () {
        $("input#getwebsiteinfo").click();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a setTimeout to the paste event did the trick, like so:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("input#websiteaddress").bind("paste", function() {
                setTimeout(function() { 
                    $("input#getwebsiteinfo").click();
                });
                return true;
            });
        });
```